# AngularJs: ng-class is not working with ui-select-choices of ui-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I want to add a `class` on `ui-select-choices`depending on the values of the `ui-select`

**[Dummy Preview on Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/3ZovOEcSH31PLlW6ppDf/)**

[source code on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZovOEcSH31PLlW6ppDf?p=preview)

I have a `UI Select` in which I am showing 2 options
1. Front
2. Back

Using `ng-class` I want to make **Front** `red` and **Back** `blue`

In order to do that I have done this:

```
<ui-select-choices 

repeat="table in (main.tables | filter: { description: $select.search }) track by table.id"

refresh="main.refreshResults($select)" 

refresh-delay="0" 

ng-class="table.description === 'Front' ? 'showRed' : 'showBlue' ">
```

**Problem** 
Both options of ui-select are blue which means `showRed` class is not getting applied to it.

*note: above is just a dummy to explain the issue that I am facing in a live project.*

Comment: I think this [github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/pull/1447/files) seems related

Comment: could you please suggest the solution as I am not able to understand the fix that is provided over the link you gave @PankajParkar Many thanks sir

Comment: I'm not sir.. Please go through them..solution is there in place.. do read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `jsfiddle.net` [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/3vMyj/2/) for that issue but I agree with Pankaj Parkar you should read explanation about this issue on github. Also this bug seems merged and fixed. If you increase your angular-ui/select-ui version it could be more useful.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
ng-class="{'showRed' : table.description === 'Front', 'showBlue' : table.description !== 'Front'}
```

Comment: Both are still BLUE and the `showBlue` class is being applied.

Comment: do care before adding an answer.. it wouldn't work.. the suggested is alternative way of what OP is trying(indeed it is correct)..